# Rust polars return ndarrays from function

Tags: function, multidimensional-array, rust

How can I make this function compile in Rust?  I want to make a function that converts Polars dataframes (and later on series) to ndarray Arrays so that I can use it in crates such as smartcore?

What do I need to add to the following code to make it compile? hmmm..

```
:dep polars = {version="*"}
:dep polars-core = {version="*",features=["ndarray"]}  
:dep ndarray = {version="*"}

use polars::prelude::*;
use ndarray::{Array,ArrayBase,Dimension,DataOwned,OwnedRepr};
fn convert_2_ndarray<D>(
    x_train:DataFrame,
    x_test:DataFrame,
)->(ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<f64>,D>,ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<f64>,D>)
    where
        D: Dimension,
    {
    
    let x_train_conv = (&x_train).to_ndarray::<Float64Type>().unwrap();
    let x_test_conv = (&x_test).to_ndarray::<Float64Type>().unwrap();
    return (x_train_conv,x_test_conv)
}
```

Tried compile code, didnt work. Following error;

```
    [E0308] Error: mismatched types
        ╭─[command_413:1:1]
        │
      3 │ fn convert_2_ndarray<D>(
        ·                      ┬  
        ·                      ╰── this type parameter
        · 
     13 │     return (x_train_conv,x_test_conv)
        ·             ──────┬─────  
        ·                   ╰─────── expected type parameter `D`, found struct `Dim`
    ────╯
    
    [E0308] Error: mismatched types
        ╭─[command_413:1:1]
        │
      3 │ fn convert_2_ndarray<D>(
        ·                      ┬  
        ·                      ╰── this type parameter
        · 
     13 │     return (x_train_conv,x_test_conv)
        ·                          ─────┬─────  
        ·                               ╰─────── expected type parameter `D`, found struct `Dim`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a generic parameter for dimension, since the dimension is constrained by `to_ndarray`:

```rust
pub fn to_ndarray<N>(&self) -> PolarsResult<Array2<N::Native>>
```

You can write:

```rust
use ndarray::Array2;
use polars::prelude::*;

fn convert_2_ndarray(x_train: DataFrame, x_test: DataFrame) -> (Array2<f64>, Array2<f64>) {
    let x_train_conv = x_train.to_ndarray::<Float64Type>().unwrap();
    let x_test_conv = x_test.to_ndarray::<Float64Type>().unwrap();
    (x_train_conv, x_test_conv)
}
```